# Removing '<and text within those>' from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm receiving an array of strings from a REST api call, and the strings have some html tags in them, for example:

```
Bard's opponents can also travel through his Magical Journey doorways. You can follow him, if you think it's safe.</li>

You can crush Bard's healing shrines just by walking over them. Don't let his allies take them without a fight.

Bard's ultimate, Tempered Fate, affects allies, enemies, monsters, and turrets alike. Sometimes it can be to your advantage to jump into it!</li>
```

Each line is a string, and two of them have an `</li>` tag at the end.

I tried writing a function that receives such an array, and returns a corrected array. Problem is, when I use it, the console in my website shows some weird errors with the strings from the array, and I've realized my function was the cause.

That is the function:

```
modal.removeBracketsFromArray = function (array) {
    if (array == undefined)
        return array;

    function removeBracketsText(text) {
        return text.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')
    };

    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        newArray.push(removeBracketsText(array[i]));
    }

    return newArray;
 };
```

It seems to do the work, but it somewhy messes up when using it in an `ng-repeat` attribute.

This is an use example:

```
<champion-ally-enemy-tips allytips="modalCtrl.removeBracketsFromArray(modalCtrl.champ.allytips)"
                          enemytips="modalCtrl.removeBracketsFromArray(modalCtrl.champ.enemytips)">
</champion-ally-enemy-tips>
```

which then moves to:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="enemytip in enemytips"><h6>{{enemytip}}</h6></li>
</ul>
```

When I remove the method call (like so), it doesn't show an error, but the tags remain:

```
<champion-ally-enemy-tips allytips="modalCtrl.champ.allytips"
                          enemytips="modalCtrl.champ.enemytips">
</champion-ally-enemy-tips>
```

Is my function doing something weird without realizing it? thanks for helping

This is a pastebin of the errors I receive: [LINK](http://pastebin.com/QQNZqff8)

Comment: Out of curiosity, you're doing a website about league of legends :P ?

Comment: Definitly :P Wanted to learn angular, and have seen riot api website for several times, thought it'd be nicer to show teemo over some weather api stuff :P

Comment: Do you by chance have angular unminified version? Maybe that error will be clearer. Also do you have the `champion-ally-enemy-tips` component we can see?

Comment: @Lex already answered it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of messing with the array, how about creating a custom filter to strip out the HTML on display?

```
.filter('removeHTML', function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '');
    }
})
```

Then change your display inside the `ng-repeat` to:

```
<h6>{{enemytip | removeHTML}}</h6>
```

Comment: Nice idea! didn't think if it. Let me check it out and return an answer

Comment: Beautiful, works and there's no error. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. :)